# function decorators in c#

Tags: c#, python, reflection, decorator

Is there a C# analog for Python's function decorators? It feels like it's doable with attributes and the reflection framework, but I don't see a way to replace functions at runtime.

[Python decorators](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) generally work this way:

```
class decorator(obj):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Before"
        self.f()
        print "After"

@decorator
def func1():
    print "Function 1"

@decorator
def func2():
    print "Function 2"
```

Calling func1 and func2 would then result in

```
Before
Function 1
After
Before
Function 2
After
```

The idea is that decorators will let me easily add common tasks at the entry and exit points of multiple functions.

Comment: I found this an interesting intro into the why as opposed to the what.
http://python.about.com/gi/dynamic/offsite.htm?zi=1/XJ&sdn=python&cdn=compute&tm=12&f=10&su=p284.9.336.ip_p504.1.336.ip_&tt=29&bt=0&bts=1&zu=http%3A//www.python.org/doc/2.4.4/whatsnew/node6.html

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping for something already built-in to the language but from the answers it looks like there is no straightforward way to do it without adding a new framework. My project is very tiny so it's probably overkill to do it that way.

Answer (score 12):

The way I achieve this is through [AOP frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) like [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html), [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html) or even the [Policy Injection Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309507.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to AOP - I think adding a framework to my tiny project might be a bit overkill though, at least for what I wanted the decorators in the first place. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

You can do that using [Post Sharp](http://www.postsharp.net/). Check out the demo video for instructions.

Comment: Post Sharp looks pretty awesome, but adding a framework to my tiny project might be a bit overkill for what I needed the function decorators for. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: It's really simple, just adding a reference and inheriting an attribute.

Comment: It also costs EUR329 after the 45-day trial period.

Comment: @Magnus there's a free version

Comment: Indeed, it was just the common case of slightly unclear marketing.

Comment: @Magnus calling their marketing awful and confusing would be giving it too much credit. The product on the other hand is great.

Answer (score 4):

you can sort of achieve that by "ContextBoundObject" in the .NET framework.
but it's a bit convoluted because it basically uses .net remoting infrastructure to intercept method calls. (the runtime overhead is minimum if your calls are within the same app domain but just across different "context").
so the better approaches would be the ones mentioned above by the other posters.