# C# method wrapper implemented with Attribute

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to implement a method wrapper in C# a similar way as eg. it's done in Python?, using attribute?
I'd like to access method's argument from inside the attribute code. 
I managed to do something similar when coding WCF application, using IOperationBehavior, but is it possible to do this using plain vanilla C# ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [function decorators in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391157/function-decorators-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). This isn't part of the .NET platform in general, but there are various options available. You might want to look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).